# How does TensorFlow name tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

I wonder if this is the correct understanding:

All tensors are derived from some operation, and operations are either given a name in the constructor, or given the default name for a particular kind of operation. If the name is not unique, TensorFlow automatically handles this by appending `"_1"`, `"_2"`, etc. An operation with n tensor outputs name these tensors `"op_name:0"`, `"op_name:1"`, ..., `"op_name:n-1"`.

One problem seems to arise: if `x` is a `tf.Variable`, then `x.name` gives `"variable_name:0"`. This is confusing: to what does `"variable_name"` refer?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your observations on `Tensor` naming are absolutely correct: the name of a `Tensor` is the concatenation of

1. the name of the operation that produced it,
2. a colon (`:`), and
3. the index of that tensor in the outputs of the operation that produced it.

Therefore the tensor named `"foo:2"` is the output of the op named `"foo"` at position 2 (with indices starting from zero).

The [naming](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.name) of [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) objects is slightly strange. Every `tf.Variable` contains a *mutable tensor* object that holds the state of the variable (and a few other tensors). A `"Variable"` op (which has the name `"variable_name"` in your example) "produces" this mutable tensor each time it is run as its 0th output, so the name of the mutable tensor is `"variable_name:0"`.

Since a `tf.Variable` is mostly indistinguishable from a `tf.Tensor`—in that it can be used in the same places—we took the decision to make variable names resemble tensor names, so the `Variable.name` property returns the name of the mutable tensor. (This contrasts with [`tf.QueueBase`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase) and [`tf.ReaderBase`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#ReaderBase) objects, which are *not* usable directly as tensors (instead you have to call methods on them to create ops that operate on their state), so these do not have a tensor-like name.)

Comment: Is there an easy way to produce the output name? Without a pb file, and only checkpoints?

Comment: is there an example to show the rule 3: **the index of that tensor in the outputs of the operation that produced it?.**

Comment: @Alpha Sure: `print(tf.split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5, name="split_op")[3].name)`, which prints the name of the tensor at index 3 in `"split_op"`'s outputs will print `"split_op:3"`.

Comment: @mrry A nitpick: it should be print(tf.split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 5, name="split_op")[3].name) (Array of size 6 does not divide into 5 parts). Thanks for your comment, by the way, it cleared everything up for me.