# What is "Const:0" in Tensor Object

Tags: python, tensorflow

In a python environment, I'm following along with ["Getting Started With TensorFlow"](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started).

```
>>> tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
# Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
>>> tf.constant(4.0) # also tf.float32 implicitly
# Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

I am wondering what the meaning and purpose is of `":0"` as the visualization of these nodes will be just `"Const"` and `"Const_1"`. Is there `":1"` for `tf.constant()`?

I searched in the source [tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py), but it doesn't seem to have my answer.

*Edit for duplicate questions on*
[How does TensorFlow name tensors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150834/how-does-tensorflow-name-tensors)

My bad for not concerning tf.Variable and having forgotten constant is also a case of variables.