# How to use get_operation_by_name() in tensorflow, from a graph built from a different function?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'd like to build a tensorflow graph in a separate function `get_graph()`, and to print out a simple ops `a` in the main function.  It turns out that I can print out the value of `a` if I return `a` from `get_graph()`.  However, if I use `get_operation_by_name()` to retrieve `a`, it print out None.  I wonder what I did wrong here? Any suggestion to fix it?  Thank you!

```
import tensorflow as tf

def get_graph():
  graph = tf.Graph()
  with graph.as_default():
    a = tf.constant(5.0, name='a')
  return graph, a  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  graph, a = get_graph()
  with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    print(sess.run(a))
    a = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('a')
    print(sess.run(a))
```

it prints out

```
5.0
None
```

p.s. I'm using python 3.4 and tensorflow 1.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naming conventions in tensorflow are subtle and a bit offsetting at first.

The thing is, when you write

```
a = tf.constant(5.0, name='a')
```

`a` is *not* the `constant` op, but its *output*. [Names of op outputs derive from the op name by adding a number corresponding to its rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150834/how-does-tensorflow-name-tensors). Here, `constant` has only one output, so its name is

```
print(a.name)
# `a:0`
```

When you run `sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('a')` you *do* get the `constant` op. But what you actually wanted is to get `'a:0'`, the tensor that is the output of this operation, and whose evaluation returns an array.

```
a = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('a:0')
print(sess.run(a))
# 5
```

Comment: thanks so much for the clarification! I also learned that I can print out the same thing by `a = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('a')` and `sess.run(a.outputs.pop())`