# Tensorflow: get output blob after operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get output of the blob

Part of the code:

```
pool5_= graph.get_tensor_by_name("pool5")
pool5_blob = sess.run([pool5_],
            feed_dict={image_placeholder: utils.image_to_batch(image)})
```

But I get error:

```
ValueError: The name 'pool5' refers to an Operation, not a Tensor. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>".
```

`pool5` exist in `[print(n.name) for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]` and not exist in `tf.all_variables()`.

So if `pool5` is operation how to get output blob after operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use get\_operation\_by\_name() in tensorflow, from a graph built from a different function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043150/how-to-use-get-operation-by-name-in-tensorflow-from-a-graph-built-from-a-diff)

Answer (score 0):

try putting a :0 after the name, like so:

```
pool5_= graph.get_tensor_by_name("pool5:0")
```

You can search around as to why this is necessary -- plenty written on it out there by qualified peops...