# TensorFlow: NotFoundError: Key not found in checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I've been training a TensorFlow model for about a week with occasional sessions of fine-tuning.

Today when I tried to finetune the model I got the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key conv_classifier/loss/total_loss/avg not found in checkpoint
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_37 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_37/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_37/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Using inspect_checkpoint.py I see that the checkpoint file now has two empty layers in it:

```
...
conv_decode4/ort_weights/Momentum (DT_FLOAT) [7,7,64,64]
loss/cross_entropy/avg (DT_FLOAT) []
loss/total_loss/avg (DT_FLOAT) []
up1/up_filter (DT_FLOAT) [2,2,64,64]
...
```

How do I fix this problem?

SOLUTION:

Following suggestion by mrry below edited for clarity:

```
code_to_checkpoint_variable_map = {var.op.name: var for var in tf.global_variables()}
for code_variable_name, checkpoint_variable_name in {
     "inference/conv_classifier/weight_loss/avg" : "loss/weight_loss/avg",
     "inference/conv_classifier/loss/total_loss/avg" : "loss/total_loss/avg",
     "inference/conv_classifier/loss/cross_entropy/avg": "loss/cross_entropy/avg",
}.items():
    code_to_checkpoint_variable_map[checkpoint_variable_name] = code_to_checkpoint_variable_map[code_variable_name]
    del code_to_checkpoint_variable_map[code_variable_name]

saver = tf.train.Saver(code_to_checkpoint_variable_map)
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./logs'))
```

Comment: Is the key `"loss/weight_loss/avg"` in the checkpoint file? The first exception message suggests that it is not. (I don't understand the other changes you've made, but the full code block looks sensible.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately, it doesn't look like your checkpoint is *corrupt*, but rather some of the variables in your program have been renamed. I'm assuming that the checkpoint value named `"loss/total_loss/avg"` should be restored to a variable named `"conv_classifier/loss/total_loss/avg"`. You can solve this by passing a custom `var_list` when you create your [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#__init__).

```
name_to_var_map = {var.op.name: var for var in tf.global_variables()}

name_to_var_map["loss/total_loss/avg"] = name_to_var_map[
    "conv_classifier/loss/total_loss/avg"]
del name_to_var_map["conv_classifier/loss/total_loss/avg"]

# Depending on how the names have changed, you may also need to do:
# name_to_var_map["loss/cross_entropy/avg"] = name_to_var_map[
#     "conv_classifier/loss/cross_entropy/avg"]
# del name_to_var_map["conv_classifier/loss/cross_entropy/avg"]

saver = tf.train.Saver(name_to_var_map)
```

You can then use `saver.restore()` to restore your model. Alternatively, you can use this approach to restore the model and a default-constructed `tf.train.Saver` to save it in the canonical format.

Comment: I'm a little confused: `name_to_var_map["loss/total_loss/avg"]` doesn't need to be (and in fact shouldn't be) present because we're assigning to it. Just a sanity check: is `name_to_var_map["conv_classifier/loss/total_loss/avg"]` present?

Comment: That's what I was expecting, yes! I tried mutating a dictionary comprehension with Python 2.7 and 3.4 and it seemed to work. Perhaps adding `name_to_var_map = dict(name_to_var_map)` will make it mutable?

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that: the original dictionary comprehension should have used `var.op.name` as the key, and not `var.name`. (The `":0"` in the `Variable.name` property is a [historical artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156697/3574081).) Does that fix things?

Comment: Sad to say stuff is still broken.  I've moved additional points to the OP below "EDIT:" because SO is giving me warnings about the comment chain.  I've deleted previous comments because of this.

Comment: Got it.  Full answer in OP.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who lands here... this is how I solved the problem:
I was running the model throught REST API & couldn't run the model for 2nd stance. Added below snippet to fix it. ( I migrated an opensource code from tf1 to tf2.

```
 # Most important to initialize all tf variables
 tf.compat.v1.initialize_all_variables().run(session=sess)
        
 if sess is None:
     self.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
            
  else:
     self.sess = sess
                 
        
  name_to_var_map = {var.op.name: var for var in tf.compat.v1.global_variables()}           
  reload_flag = False

  # This list may vary based on the model used. Print the var_map to check
  new_tags_added_after_first_run = ['J_regressor_1','cocoplus_regressor_1','lbs_weights_1','mean_param_1','shapedirs_1','posedirs_1','v_template_1'] 
   
   for name in new_tags_added_after_first_run :
      if name in name_to_var_map.keys():            
          # del name_to_var_map[name]
          reload_flag = True    # This indicates, 1st run is done
          break
        
   if reload_flag :  # After first load
       self.saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver(name_to_var_map)
       self.mean_value = self.sess.run(self.mean_var)
   else:            # On first load
       self.saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver(name_to_var_map)         
       self.prepare()
```

As the model is already cached, I refrain from loading it multiple times in memory.

Hope it helps!