# What characters are allowed in tensorflow variable names?

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, graph, scope

When choosing a name for a tensorflow variable, this is ok:

```
>> tf.Variable(2, name='a')

<tf.Variable 'finegrained_1/decoder/unreadable/a:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
```

However, this is not:

```
>> tf.Variable(2, name='a:b')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/mm/appy-finegrained/sign_classification/model_finegrained.py in <module>()
----> 1 tf.Variable(2, name='a:b')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in __init__(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, variable_def, dtype, expected_shape, import_scope, constraint)
    211           dtype=dtype,
    212           expected_shape=expected_shape,
--> 213           constraint=constraint)
    214 
    215   def __repr__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in _init_from_args(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, expected_shape, constraint)
    287     with ops.control_dependencies(None):
    288       with ops.name_scope(name, "Variable", [] if init_from_fn else
--> 289                           [initial_value]) as name:
    290 
    291         if init_from_fn:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __enter__(self)
   4930       self._g_manager.__enter__()
   4931       self._name_scope = g.name_scope(self._name)
-> 4932       return self._name_scope.__enter__()
   4933 
   4934   def __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
     79     def __enter__(self):
     80         try:
---> 81             return next(self.gen)
     82         except StopIteration:
     83             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in name_scope(self, name)
   3512         # (viz. '-', '\', '/', and '_').
   3513         if not _VALID_SCOPE_NAME_REGEX.match(name):
-> 3514           raise ValueError("'%s' is not a valid scope name" % name)
   3515       else:
   3516         # Scopes created in the root must match the more restrictive

ValueError: 'a:b' is not a valid scope name
```

Putting a `/` in a name is allowed, but it probably breaks some scoping things:

```
>> tf.Variable(2, name='a/b')

<tf.Variable 'finegrained_1/decoder/unreadable/a/b:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
```

**Are there any defined rules as to what character set is allowed in variable names?**

And (with regards to the `a/b` name) **are there any extra guidelines for what shouldn't be used?**

Comment: You can always play it safe and stick to `a-Z`, `0-9` and `_`.

Comment: The `:N` suffix identifies a specific _tensor_ in the node whose name you're specifying. That's why you can't have `:` in the name. For all those occasions where you need to specify a tensor name, when no suffix is specified, `:0` is implied. So, for example `get_tensor_by_name('a')` and `get_tensor_by_name('a:0')` both will return the first tensor of the output of node `a`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for ops naming, see [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#__init__) documentation:

> NOTE: This constructor validates the name of the `Operation` (passed as
>   `node_def.name`). Valid `Operation` names match the following regular
>   expression:
>
> ```
> [A-Za-z0-9.][A-Za-z0-9_.\\-/]*
> ```

Each variable is translated into a number of ops, and its name is put into the *scope*, which naming rules are very similar (see [`python/framework/ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L1461)):

```
_VALID_OP_NAME_REGEX = re.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9.][A-Za-z0-9_.\\-/]*$")
_VALID_SCOPE_NAME_REGEX = re.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9_.\\-/]*$")
```

Naturally, `'/'` and `':'` are not allowed in the name, since they are used for internal tensorflow purposes:

- `'/'` is a separator of nested scopes (the regex allows it, but this means using *several scopes* in a single declaration);
- `':'` is a separator of tensor name and output index (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36150834/712995) for details).

Answer (score 0):

You can give your ops names with capital letters but you should absolutely **not** do it. Here's a nice little failure case for you tested in TF 2.8 (yes, the model is nonsense):

```py
input1 = keras.Input(shape=2, name='a')
input2 = keras.Input(shape=2, name='A')
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Average()([input1, input2])

dummy = keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=outputs)
dummy.summary()

dummy.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

dummy.save("dummy.savedmodel")
```

Summary works fine, compile works fine, fitting the model is probably fine(?) but you can't save it. Because something with `absl` converts to lowercase and then you can get collisions of names.

Unfortunately, I can't find the rules for Tensorflow naming (if the TF developers can't either then that might explain this weird behaviour). But I would stick to [a-z0-9_]. I tested length up to about 17000 character long names and that seemed to work fine but keep in mind that other tools in your pipeline may have other limits, e.g. a column name in PostgreSQL is usually limited to 63 characters.