# difference between variable name and tensor name in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am confused by the variable name and tensor name in tensorflow. My understanding is as follows:

1. A tensor name consists of the op_name and index.
2. The variable name is given by us when we define variables.
   For instance, if we do

> > > a = tf.Variable([1,2],name='defined_a')
> > >
> > > print(a.name)
> > >
> > > 'defined_a:0'

which one of them  is the correct variable name, `defined_a:0` or `defined_a`? 
Also, if we save the graph in a meta file, which name will be saved, defined_a:0 or defined_a?

Can anyone helps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does TensorFlow name tensors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150834/how-does-tensorflow-name-tensors)