# Tensor named kernel:1 or bias:1 in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras, keras-layer

In keras, weight tensors are named as [layer's name]/kernel:0 or [layer's name]/bias:0, is there any case where they will be named kernel:1 or bias:1? If not, then what the 0 represents there?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150834/how-does-tensorflow-name-tensors?

Comment: So is it possible for having a weight variable named kernel:1 or bias:1?